# How to force full resync on slave

Tags: debian, openldap

I have an *openldap* master and 2 slaves, synced using *syncrepl*. It worked fine until recently but after a long shutdown of one slave some removed entries are still present on it (they are absent from master and other slave).

I tried to restart the slave, I also started a forced sync on slave with `slapd -c rid=NNN,csn=0` (NNN is the RID for master link): slave do ask again for all entries but never drop these deleted entries.

I can of course reconfigure from stratch this slave, or stop replication on this slave and then remove entries but I guess/hope that it exists a command similar to `slapd -c rid=NNN,csn=0` that also takes in count missing entries.

At this time all my ldaps (master/slaves) are on up-to-date Debian 8 64bit with native openldap packages.

Any clues about:

- why this happens?
- are they ways to prevent it to happen again?
- simplest way to correct this slave?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks… I still read this documentation. Maybe I missed an important point related to my problem but then something more precise than a pointer to a 55k text page would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have syncprov-reloadhint set to?

Comment: My sync config on slaves is olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=1 provider=ldaps://master-address
  type=refreshAndPersist bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=synagent,dc=my,dc=dc" credentials=the-passwd retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1  tls_reqcert=never. From the doc I followed I did not set the reloadhint value.

Comment: You do not say if you are using the accesslog overlay for delta-based syncrepl, but if you are you need to set `syncprov-reloadhint` to true. Maybe this will solve your issue. See also the man page for `slapo-syncprov`.

Comment: I will add this option and check. Will come back to report the effects. Thanks.

Comment: No change. At this time I removed SyncRepl on this slave, deleted all entries, restarted slapd with -c option and it is now in sync (after I re-added SyncRepl of course). The remaining entries were a real production problem.